# Get public IP address of API Management from ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I got this API Management ARM template

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('am-apimanagement-service-name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('am-sku')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('am-skuCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisherEmail": "[parameters('am-publisher-email-p')]",
        "publisherName": "[parameters('am-publisher-name-p')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "apis",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
          "name": "test",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/',variables('am-apimanagement-service-name'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "displayName": "test",
            "description": "",
            "serviceUrl": "[concat('https://test-',parameters('environment'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "path": "test",
            "protocols": [
              "https"
            ],
            "isCurrent": true
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
              "type": "operations",
              "name": "GetTEst",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/', variables('am-apimanagement-service-name'), '/apis/test')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "displayName": "GET",
                "method": "GET",
                "urlTemplate": "/api/sites",
                "description": "Get"
              }
            }
          ]

        }
      ]
    }
```

And this Web API ARM template

```
   {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('swa-name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('swa-name')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[variables('swa-hosting-plan-name')]",
        "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('swa-hosting-environment')]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "Test:ConnectionString",
              "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:', reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('db-serverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', variables('db-databaseName'), ';Persist Security Info=False;User ID=', parameters('db-administratorLogin'), ';Password=', parameters('db-administratorLoginPassword'), ';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;')]"
            }
          ],
          "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
            {
              "ipAddress": "[variables('test-ip-address')]",
              "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "location": "[parameters('swa-location')]",
      "tags": {

      },
      "kind": "api",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('swa-hosting-plan-name'))]"
      ]
    }
```

How do I use the reference function to get IP address of the API Management resource from the Web API ? I want to put the API Management IP address in the ipSecurityRestrictions. I can not figure it out, and it is frustrating me quite a bit.

I have tried this from the web api resource resource section of the ARM template:

```
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
            {
              "ipAddress": "[variables('test-ip-address')]",
              "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255"
            },
            {
              "ipAddress": "[reference(variables('am-apimanagement-service-name')).publicIPAddresses[0]]",
              "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255"
            }
          ]
```

But it doesnt work. Maybe I am not able to get the IP address in this step of the process? I am reading about outputs and linked templates. Maybe this is the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crazy thing here is that I need two things:

1. apiVersion to the reference
2. I need to reference the staticIp property

The thing is that a free tier API Management resource is actually not assigned a static IP, but a dynamic ip. Still the static ip address is assigned to the staticIp property of the referenced object:

```
"ipAddress": "[reference(variables('am-apimanagement-service-name'),'2017-03-01').staticIps[0]]"
```

This will reference the IP correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add the api version to your reference, as the API management is not deployed in the same template as where you're refering to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#reference

Something like this

```
{
          "ipAddress": "[reference(variables('am-apimanagement-service-name'), '2017-03-01').publicIPAddresses[0]]",
          "subnetMask": "255.255.255.255"
}
```

Comment: That is actually partially right. I can get the ip address from the staticIp address. I will add an answer to this question. I have upvoted your answer.